# How to send csv as email attachment in laravel 4.2?

Tags: php, csv, laravel-4, email-attachments

I want  to send CSV file as an attachment with email in laravel 4.2
I have already generated a csv file, but doesn't have any clue for sending it with email.

This is the controller from where the csv method is called --

```
$this->report->generateCSV($schedule_type->name,$schedule_type->date_from,$schedule_type->date_to,$schedule_type->company_name,$csvHeader,$reportData,$filename.'.csv',';',$array);
```

and this is the function which generated output

```
public function generateCSV($reportname,$startdate,$enddate,$companyname,$csvHeader,$csvDataArray,$filename='report.csv',$delimiter=';',$elementsOfCSV = array()){
        header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
        $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
        fputcsv($fp, array(' ', ' ' ), $delimiter);
        fputcsv($fp, array(' ','Report Name : ',$reportname), $delimiter);
        fputcsv($fp, array(' ','Run date : ',date('Y-m-d')), $delimiter);
        fputcsv($fp, array(' ','Date period being reported : ',$startdate.' to '.$enddate), $delimiter);
        if($companyname)
        fputcsv($fp, array(' ','Client Company : ',$companyname), $delimiter);
        fputcsv($fp, array(' ','   ',' '), $delimi  ter);
        fputcsv($fp, array(' ','  ',' '), $delimiter);
        fputcsv($fp, $csvHeader, $delimiter);
        $i= $avgTimeTaken = $avgPercentage = 0;
        $totalRow = count($csvDataArray);
        if($totalRow > 0){
        foreach ($csvDataArray as $k=>$data) {
             $csvData[$k][$i] = ' ';
            foreach ($data as $key=>$line) {
                if(in_array($key, $elementsOfCSV)){
                    if($key=='time_taken'){
                        $line = gmdate("H:i:s", $line);
                    }
                    $csvData[$k][$key] = $line; 
                }
            }
            fputcsv($fp, $csvData[$k], $delimiter); 
            $i++;            
        }  
        }

        fclose($fp);
    }
```

I know how to send attachment. Which I have used for sending PDF file as an attachment

```
Mail::send('site/user/mailcertificate', array('key' => 'value'), function($message) use ($pdfPath, $userDetails)
{
     $message->from('abc@gmail.com', 'Message Subject');
     $message->to($userDetails['userEmail'], $userDetails['userName'])->subject('Assessment Certificate');
     $message->attach($pdfPath);
 }
```

But the function which is written here force me download the CSV file.
So how can I make it to send it as email attachment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an easy solution.
Firstly I created a blank `.csv` file in the destination folder manually.
Suppose that a file named `"Report.csv"` was created inside the directory `public/uploads/report.csv`.

Then it was an easy task.

I opened the file for writing content with the following command --

```
$fp = fopen(public_path('uploads/report.csv'), 'w');
```

Here `w` is used for erasing the last content of file and giving permission to insert new data.

Now I used the following lines for attaching the file with the mail

```
define('CSV_Ddefine('CSV_DIR', public_path('uploads')); 

if (!is_dir(CSV_DIR)){
   mkdir(CSV_DIR, 0755, true);
}

$outputName = str_random(10); 
$csvPath = CSV_DIR.'/report.csv';

foreach($emails as $email) {
    Mail::send('admin/report/mailscheduledreport', array('filename' => $filename), function($message) use ($csvPath, $email)
    {
         $message->from('info@abc.com', 'Reports');
         $message->to($email)->subject('Reports');                
         $message->attach($csvPath);
     });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should generate CSV and save it in `public/some-folder` and then attach it from there. Rather than generating CSV and downloading it.

Comment: Simple and a hack! generate the content and write it to a file.

Comment: there are so many resources available online. please do search and work. here is one from php manual, check this out and search for more http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php